# FREEIPA LDAP Server not working : [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: ldap, freeipa

[root@ipa ~]# ipa -v ping
ipa: INFO: trying https://ipa.ca.example.com/ipa/json
ipa: INFO: Connection to https://ipa.ca.example.com/ipa/json failed with [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)
ipa: INFO: trying https://ipa2.ca.example.com/ipa/json
ipa: INFO: Connection to https://ipa2.ca.example.com/ipa/json failed with [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)
ipa: ERROR: cannot connect to 'any of the configured servers': https://ipa.ca.example.com/ipa/json, https://ipa2.ca.example.com/ipa/json

Comment: [root@ipa ~]# ipa-cacert-manage renew
CA certificate is not tracked by certmonger
The ipa-cacert-manage command failed.

Comment: [root@ipa ~]# ipa-certupdate
trying https://ipa.ca.example.com/ipa/json
Connection to https://ipa.ca.example.com/ipa/json failed with [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)
trying https://ipa2.ca.example.com/ipa/json
Connection to https://ipa2.ca.example.com/ipa/json failed with [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)
cannot connect to 'any of the configured servers': https://ipa.ca.example.com/ipa/json, https://ipa2.ca.example.com/ipa/json
The ipa-certupdate command failed.